# Refer reST label in python docstring

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I want to refer to reST label in my python method docstring and am expecting Sphinx to generate appropriate links.

I tried the following which does not work for me.

### myown.rst

```
.. my-label:
   Some explanation ...
```

### mymodule.py

```
def somefunc():
    """ See :ref:`my-label`. """
    ... rest of the code ...
```

This produces "See my-label" as text in the generated html file while I am expecting it to create appropriate hyper-link.

I see this kind of references in python-docs (e.g. see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod ) and reference to Function definitions (which is generic explanation). However, this is not generated from docstrings (as can be seen from funcobject.c) .. so I am inclined to think that it is handcrafted rst !!

Comment: Try using single quotes `:ref:'my-label'`

Comment: @Pynchia. No luck. single quote (" ' ") or back quote(" ' ") still generates a string.

Comment: Simple typo, it seems... The label is missing an underscore. It should be `.. _my-label:`

Comment: @mzjn. Thanks for pointing that out. My bad while adding the question. However, that does not help. Sphinx still generates a string and not a link.

Comment: Do you see any warnings from Sphinx? It looks like your label is not placed before a section title. See http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/inline.html#role-ref

Comment: @mzjn. Thank you for pointing the way. There was no specific warning for this but the section title indeed was missed. I knew it was something very silly on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comment from @mzjn - the section header was missing in the rst file. Adding that and regenerating fixes the issue.